# How to add a shortcut key to menuitem WPF

Tags: wpf

i am trying to add a shortcut key to a menuitem(when i press a combination of keys, i want it to activate the click event of the menuItem) this is the Xaml code i am using:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="mi1" Header= "_Iniciar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Click="button_Click" Margin="0,0,-10,0" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I" Command="{Binding }">


                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="C:\Users\alans\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication4\img/oscu.png" Margin="-4,0,-2,0" >

                    </Image>

                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
```

Comment: a quick documentation search reveals following: This property does not associate the input gesture with the menu item; it simply adds text to the menu item. The application must handle the user's input to carry out the action. For information on how to associate a command with a menu item, see Command.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out, [`InputGestureText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext) does not actually hook up a gesture, to do that you need to use a [`KeyBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keybinding) in conjuction with a [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview), like so:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="mi1" Header= "_Iniciar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Click="button_Click" Margin="0,0,-10,0" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I" Command="{Binding }">
    <MenuItem.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+I" Command=""/>
    </MenuItem.InputBindings>
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\alans\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication4\img/oscu.png" Margin="-4,0,-2,0"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

You will need to define your own command or leverage an existing one to fill in the blank in the code above.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Thank you, this works very well for me.

Comment: @alansmith You're welcome. Please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then. Happy coding.